# Why is bundle adding an extra 0 at the end of my Ruby version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I'm trying to install dependencies by running `bundle install`.

My `Gemfile` specifies Ruby version as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.6.6'


gem 'cocoapods', '1.10.2'
...
```

However when I run `bundle install` I get the following output:

```
geoff:PayPalMobileSafariExtension git:(develop*) $ bundle install
Fetching <internal URL>
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler found conflicting requirements for the Ruby version:
  In Gemfile:
    Ruby (~> 2.6.6.0)

    <some-internal-dependency> was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      Ruby (= 2.6.6)
```

It's saying that I specified Ruby version 2.6.6.0 which is completely nonsensical, no such Ruby version exists and that's not even in the `Gemfile`. What is causing this?

For context I am using `rbenv` to manage my Ruby versions, it is currently set to 2.6.6.

Comment: It looks like rbenv doesn't care about the Ruby version in the Gemfile. https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/727. So the question could be, is "2.6.6.0" being set in one source from this list? https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this may have been due to a conflict between `gem install`ed gems and `bundle install`ing the same gems over again.
Doing `gem uninstall -aIx` and then `bundle install` may fix this.